# When I link the mapping node to the gradient node my sphere turns black. How do I fix this?

Tags: shaders, shader-nodes

[image: sphere before nodes linked]

[image: sphere after nodes linked]

Before and after linking the nodes. I am trying to create a partially transparent cornea for context! The entire sphere keeps turning black when I link the mapping node to the gradient texture node.

Comment: hello could you please share your file? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If a *Texture Coordinate* input is not present, the space in which the *Gradient > Linear* is measured defaults to ***Generated***.

***Generated*** space measures 0-1 along the sides of an object's bounding box, aligned to the object's own X,Y and Z axes. In that space, the minimum X of your sphere's surface maps to 0, and its maximum X maps to 1.

An un-rotated *Linear Gradient* varies along X of the given space. The output of that node in ***Generated*** space is 0 at the left of your sphere, and 1 at the right. The Color Ramp expects a 0-1 input. In this case, that's what it's getting, and mapping that range as determined by the sliders.

When you connected the Texture Coordinate node, you chose ***Object*** space for the gradient. That space is measured in Blender Units, from the object's origin, along its axes. The sphere's origin is still at its center, and it's 0.172 units in diameter.

In ***Object*** space, the sphere's minimum X is -0.086 ,and its maximum X is +0.086. That's the range the *Color Ramp* is getting as input. All the negative values are off the left of the ramp. The positive values will be mapped to whatever is between 0 and 0.086 in the ramp. In this case, Black.

**TLDR;**

To get the same results as before, use the ***Generated*** output of the *Texture Coordinate* node

Comment: Hi Robin - thank you for this! It worked... until I changed the the Z rotation coordinates. Do you know why this is? 

Sorry if you covered this previously, I'm relatively new to Blender!

Comment: You would expect the Generated texture-space  to stick to the object if it's rotated in Object Mode. The object's bounding box travels with it. What effect are you looking for? Lit side of a planet, or something like that?

Comment: @Emma  Ahh! You mean in the mapping node? Generated's origin is at min (XYZ) so that's the rotation pivot.  You may want a rotation about the middle of the sphere. Use a Vector Rotate node instead of a Mapping node, Axis Angle, and set the origin to (0.5,0.5,0.5) .

Comment: It worked Robin! Thank you so much :D

Comment: @EmmaCulhane For the use of the _Texture Coordinate_ node and the differences between _Generated_ and _Object_ output and possible conversions, there is a YT channel by some guy (or actually two channels), he does a lot of procedural stuff with _Texture Coordinates_. His tutorials are a bit... unconventional, but I've learned a lot about normal vector manipulation etc. from that. The channels are called "Default Cube" and "CG Matter". It comes in quite handy sometimes if you know how to use the different types of coordinates and when it's better to use _Generated_, _Object_ or _UV_  etc.

Answer (score 1):

Since your using the object coordinates, I think it might be caused by not applying the transformation.
I presume you changed the scale of the object somewhere.

so the solution is to apply the transformation :D

Select the sphere and hit Ctrl+A and select All transformations.